# AppFolder listChildren MetadataBuffer becomes unexpectedly empty after some hours

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm using the AppFolder, and successfully reading/writing files to that folder. I can write a file to that folder on one device and read it on another device (using the same Google account).

However, every morning I wake up and find listChildren on the AppFolder returns an empty MetadataBuffer. When I look in Manage Apps section of the Google Drive website, there is clearly something (40KB) in my app's AppFolder.

What could be the possible reasons for this?

EDIT: Added some code

```
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
  DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClient);
  folder.listChildren(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(mChildrenRetrievedCallback);

...

mChildrenRetrievedCallback = new ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {
  public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {
    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
      // oh noes!
      return;
    }
    MetadataBuffer buffer = result.getMetadataBuffer();
    // buffer.getCount() is 0
```

Comment: can you show the code you are using to list children?  If you list children right away do you get different behavio?

Comment: You say "I can write a file to that folder on one device and read it on another". Consider yourself lucky. I can do the same reliably only when reverting to RESTful for query (I can still write through GDAA). Querying / reading with GDAA is a coin toss. On 2 devices with the same account, wifi connected, it takes random amount of time to synchronize even if I use 'resource' or 'encoded' id, bypassing querying. And I can't make notifications work, making all this endeavor kind of useless.